# Web service Spring ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, spring-mvc

I'm trying to call a web service with ajax. The service is up, and it can shows the result on the RestClient on firefox, but, in mi application call, gives me Status error "Pending".

This is my simple web service.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")

public class HelloWs {


@RequestMapping(value= "/helloWorld", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json")

        public @ResponseBody String  HelloWorld() {


            return "Hello Worldssss¡¡";

        }
```

And this is my ajax call.

```
function hellowsfunction() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"http://localhost:8080/ehCS-ui/rest/hello/helloWorld",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "JSON",
        headers : {Accept : "applicationjson","Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"},
            success: function(msg) {

             var returnedData = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
             $("#lblResult")
            .text(result)
            .slideUp("hide", function() { $(this).slideDown("slow") });
     },
      error: function (e) { 
            $("#lblResult").removeClass("loading");
            alert('failed:'+e);
            console.log(e);
             }
     });
```

what is wrong? Ideas?¿ please help.
Thanks

Comment: as a side note, `crossDomain: true` isn't needed since this actually is a crossDomain reqeust. The Access-Control headers need to be set on the server.

Comment: HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); do you refer to something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `@RequestMapping` is wrong... you should not map based on `Accept` header like this. Instead you should use `produces` parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/helloWorld", method=RequestMethod.GET, 
    produces={"application/xml", "application/json"})
```

Also your header in the JS is incorrect. Just remove their specification completely.

Comment: Hi pavel, I'm using spring 3.0.5 and it doesn´t have the produces anotation yet. Is there another solution without that? It gives me the same error in the javascript console: "Failure Object: object" Thanks

Comment: Can't you upgrade to newer Spring? That would make your life much easier... I personally consider 3.2.x to be the first mature 3.x release.

Comment: Exists another solution without this spring version?

Comment: Definitely... but I'll need to check what is actually in Spring 3.0.5. Btw. in the JS you have `dataType: "JSON"`... not sure whether this is not case sensitive.